# Python subprocess - returned non-zero exit status 1

Tags: python, python-3.x, unix, subprocess, wkhtmltopdf

I want to execute this `UNIX` command using `python 3.6` and `subprocess` module:

```
 cat report_html | ./wkhtmltopdf - test.pdf
```

**What I tried**

```
import subprocess
report_html = "<html><body><h1>Hello World</h1></body></html>"
subprocess.run(['cat', report_html, '|', '/tmp/wkhtmltopdf', '-', '/tmp/test.pdf'], check=True)
```

**Error I am getting**

```
{
  "errorMessage": "Command '['cat', '<html><body><h1>Hello World</h1></body></html>', '|', '/tmp/wkhtmltopdf', '-', '/tmp/test.pdf']' returned non-zero exit status 1.",
  "errorType": "CalledProcessError",
  "stackTrace": [
    [
      "/var/task/lambda_function.py",
      30,
      "lambda_handler",
      "subprocess.run(['cat', report_html, '|', '/tmp/wkhtmltopdf', '-', '/tmp/test.pdf'], check=True)"
    ],
    [
      "/var/lang/lib/python3.6/subprocess.py",
      438,
      "run",
      "output=stdout, stderr=stderr)"
    ]
  ]
}
```

Please guide me on how to fix this.

Answer (score 1):

---

If you want to use pipe in `subprocess`, you must use `shell=True` argument, which is not the best solution for multiple reasons.

Usually, this is done by running two separate processes and pass the output of the first one into the second one, for example:

```
cat = subprocess.Popen(['cat', 'report_html'], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)  # Change stdout to PIPE
output = subprocess.check_output(['wkhtmltopdf', '-', 'xxx.pdf'], stdin=cat.stdout)  # Get stdin from cat.stdout
```